# Profile picture size is off on response feed on mobile web version

Tags: bug, mobile-web, profile-picture

[image]

Using Chrome on Huawei P9, using latest updates of Android.

To further clarify. This is not something that happens with this particular user. There are a number of examples just like this. Also it doesn't happen with all custom avatars, as is already shown in the image.